# Game Center authentication in spritekit ios8

Tags: ios, game-center

With ios8, did apple change the way you authenticate players. I've used:

```
- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews
{
[super viewWillLayoutSubviews];

// Configure the view.
SKView * skView = (SKView *)self.view;
if (!skView.scene) {


    // Create and configure the scene.
    SKScene * scene = [MainMenu sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];
    scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;


    [skView presentScene:scene];
    [self authenticateLocalPlayer];

}
}
- (void) authenticateLocalPlayer
{
GKLocalPlayer *localPlayer = [GKLocalPlayer localPlayer];
[localPlayer authenticateWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
    if (localPlayer.isAuthenticated)
    {
        // Perform additional tasks for the authenticated player.
    }
}];
```

}

in other games and it worked fine, but now it crashes as soon as the app loads. Any ideas why?

Comment: Where does it crash?

Comment: @jonogilmour Right at the start. The first scene will be displayed for about half a second before it crashes.

Comment: That doesn't tell us much. What line specifically does it crash at? Consider using breakpoints and/or printing to figure out the location. Also what type of error are you getting? Can you paste in as much information about the error as you can?

Comment: @jonogilmour I know [self authenticateLocalPlayer]; is causing it cause when i remove it theres no crash. When it does crash, it doesnt show the error at the bottom, it takes me to the main.m file and shows the debug navigator on the left, where do i go from there to find the type of error.

Comment: Still, we need to know exactly where it crashes. It's just as likely that the stuff inside `if (localPlayer.isAuthenticated)` is causing the crash and removing ` [self authenticateLocalPlayer]` is preventing any of that from happening.

Comment: @jonogilmour i just found this      2014-11-11 01:43:26.506 ZombieConga[5196:589828] -[GKLocalPlayerInternal name]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x796aa9c0

Comment: That essentially means that you are trying to call a method, or get to a property, that doesn't exist. Can you post the code within the `if (localPlayer.isAuthenticated)` part? That may be the broken code, assuming there is code in there.

Comment: @jonogilmour there isnt anything in there

Comment: add an `NSLog(@"here\n");` in between `GKLocalPlayer *localPlayer = [GKLocalPlayer localPlayer];` and `[localPlayer...` and see if it prints. If it does, the problem is in the latter, if not, it's the former.

Comment: @jonogilmour It did print. authenticatewithcompletionhandler: is deprecated since ios 6. It worked in 7, could it not longer work at all in 8? What can i replace it with?

Comment: It's entirely possible it has been removed completely with iOS 8. Even if it hasn't, running deprecated code is a risky practice. That method has been replaced with a different way entirely. You set the authentication handler using `localPlayer.authenticateHandler` and setting it to a block. This method is widely documented, but this post may give you a good idea of what to do exactly: http://www.raywenderlich.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=9045

Comment: Personally I have only done this in Swift, but my implementation looks like `localPlayer.authenticateHandler = {(viewController, error) -> //block here` and it works